# Equivalent to yum history?

Tags: 10.10, package-management, command-line, apt

Is there an equivalent to `yum history` command in ubuntu? Im aware that i can just look at the apt logs, but im looking for something that will list them all in the command line, and then enable me to target a specific installation and rollback / modify it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find it in GNOME Menu System - Administration :

1.- GUI > find ..... **synaptic** package manager > file > history.

2.- In the terminal either `/var/log/apt/history.log` or `/var/log/dpkg.log`

Comment: Both method give partial results, only packages installed/removed with synaptic or apt-get respectively. They do not cover aptitude. The only comprehensive log is /var/log/dpkg.log